# Errors in java mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql

I have been trying to write a Java program which connects to `mysql` db and retreives data from it.

I have written a simple program which worked successfully, but the below snippet throws some errors which I even  havent heard of.

The snippet is as follows:

```
public class test{
String rows,rows1;
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,"root","");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

String query="select distinct(username) from tracking";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next())
{
rows=rs.getString("username");
System.out.println(rows);
String query1="select distinct(session_id) from tracking where username='"+rows+"'";
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery(query1);
while(rs1.next())
{
rows1=rs1.getString("session_id");
String query2="select * from tracking where username='"+rows+"' and session_id='"+rows1+"'";
ResultSet rs2=stmt.executeQuery(query2);
while(rs2.next())
{
System.out.println("Result"+rs2.getString("method"));
}
}
}
con.close();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

catch(SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
};
```

The errors are as follows

```
test.java:12: error: non-static variable dbUrl cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,"root","");
                                              ^
test.java:19: error: non-static variable rows cannot be referenced from a static
 context
rows=rs.getString("username");
^
test.java:20: error: non-static variable rows cannot be referenced from a static
 context
System.out.println(rows);
                   ^
test.java:21: error: non-static variable rows cannot be referenced from a static
 context
String query1="select distinct(session_id) from tracking where username='"+rows+
"'";
                                                                           ^
test.java:25: error: non-static variable rows1 cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
rows1=rs1.getString("session_id");
^
test.java:26: error: non-static variable rows cannot be referenced from a static
 context
String query2="select * from tracking where username='"+rows+"' and session_id='
"+rows1+"'";
                                                        ^
test.java:26: error: non-static variable rows1 cannot be referenced from a stati
c context
String query2="select * from tracking where username='"+rows+"' and session_id='
"+rows1+"'";
```

I am unable to understand the errors here.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but you have to step back, forget MySQL and do some basic Java tutorials. The problems you have have *nothing* to do with MySQL/JDBC, they are all just basic Java mistakes. Also, if you get the code to compile, it's vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Make sure you don't start learning with bad practices, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: learn from your errors its very simple from the error that you are making mistake at basic level  review your code with respect your error you will find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your variables STATIC.

```
static String rows,rows1;
static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
static String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

You are using the variables rows, rows1 etc in your MAIN method which is static. Whenever you are using any variables inside a static method, the variables itself has to be static.

Probably you are making one of the [common errors in Java](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html). May be you can go through other types of common errors so that you can avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution here is to just make your variables static:

```
static String rows,rows1;
static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
static String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

or move them to within `main`, assuming you're going to stick with your current "do everything in `main`" strategy).

The problem you have is that `main` is a static class and therefore is run without the benefit of an instance of your class. It can therefore only access members that are defined at class level (one per class, or one across *all* instances of a class).

Because your four strings are currently *instance* variables (one for *each* instance of the class), they can only be referenced via their instance.

It may help to think of the distinction in this way:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| xyzzy class                                   |
|    (class variables here, shared amongst      |
|     all instances and static methods)         |
|                                               |
|  +------------------+   +------------------+  |
|  | xyzzy instance 1 |   | xyzzy instance 2 |  |
|  |    (instance 1   |   |    (instance 2   |  |
|  |     variables    |   |     variables    |  |
|  |     here only    |   |     here only    |  |
|  |     for this     |   |     for this     |  |
|  |     instance)    |   |     instance)    |  |
|  +------------------+   +------------------+  |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

---

You also don't need `dbClass` at all since you don't actually use it. You should either use it in the `forName` call, or get rid of it altogether.

Comment: Actually, the best solution would probably to make them local variables instead of static fields, since they are only used in `main`.

Comment: @Joachim, that's another good option of course, adding to answer.

Answer (score 0):

dbURL,dbClass, row and row1 all should be static variables.

declare them as static.

Answer (score -2):

Try wacking the "static" in front of the varibles its having trouble with, for an explanation between what static and non static objects are: [this might help](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html)